# Gibt es im Deutschen ein Nomen, das im Plural unverändert bleibt?

Tags: vocabulary, grammatical-number

Also wie bei den englischen "fish", "sheep", "hair", usw.

Bitte antwortet auf Deutsch.

Comment: Ich war zunächst unentschieden, diese Frage als _zu unspezifisch (too broad)_ zu schliessen. Aber es scheint bis zu einem gewissen Grad ein Muster zu geben.

Comment: Das [“Nomen”](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nomen) im Titel Deiner Frage wäre schon mal das erste Beispiel... ;-)

Comment: An sich ist nicht ganz klar, was du eigentlich fragst. Deine englischen Beispiele sind *Abstrakta*, die man im Deutschen eben einfach nicht in den Plural setzt, auch wenn man z.B. viele Fische meint - Auch an der Nordsee wird in Deutschland "viel Fisch" gefangen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gibt es im Deutschen ein Nomen, das bei seiner Pluralsform sich nicht verändert?

Im Bereich Berufsbezeichnungen gibt es sehr viele Beispiele, wenn sie generell der maskulinen Form folgen, z.B. *Der Techniker => Die Techniker*, *Der Bäcker => Die Bäcker*, *Der Schuster => Die Schuster*, etc., etc.

Vgl. *Die Floristin => Die Floristinnen*, *Die Erzieherin => Die Erzieherinnen*.

Man könnte nun daraus herleiten, das jedes dieser Nomen jeweils eine maskuline und eine feminine Grundform haben, und sich die Pluralform endend auf *-innen* eben dementsprechend ändert.

Dies wird jedoch aktuell vor dem Hintergrund der Geschlechtergleichstellung, und ihrer Reflexion in *"korrekter"* Sprache zur Zeit sehr kontrovers diskutiert<sup>1</sup>.  Im Plural sollten beide Geschlechter korrekt repräsentiert sein, im Gegensatz zu einer Repräsentation eines spezifischen Individuums.

---

Aber es gibt auch andere Nomen, die sich nicht auf Menschen beziehen und deren Schreibweise im Plural sich im Vergleich zu der Hauptform nicht ändert (und dementsprechend die oben erwähnte Argumentation einer normalisierten Pluralschreibweise keinen Sinn ergeben würde):

- *Der Felsen => Die Felsen*
- *Der Kater => Die Kater*
- *Der Bräter => Die Bräter*<sup>2</sup>
- *Der Schraubenzieher => Die Schraubenzieher*

---

Ich kann das jetzt nur empirisch belegen, aber es scheint so, dass all diese Nomen eine maskuline Grundform haben.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Siehe auch [Geschlechtergerechte Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache), [Gendergap](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendergap_(Linguistik)), [Binnen-I](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnen-I).</sub>
<sup>2)</sup><sub>Ein spezieller Kochtopf.</sub>

Comment: das Mittel, das Mädchen, das Opfer, das Leben, ...

Comment: @Hubert Ich habe offenbar die _neutralen_ Formen übersehen, wie in [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50339/28897) erwähnt.

Comment: Die Spaghetti / die Spaghetti https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spaghetti_Teigware_Nudel

Comment: @infinitezero: Eigentlich (wenn man die italienische Wurzel beachtet): Der Spaghetto

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Diese Formen sind nicht *neutral* sondern *sächlich*. Die drei grammatischen Geschlechter sind: männlich, weiblich und sächlich. "Neutral" ist kein Begriff der deutschen Grammatik.

Answer (score 8):

Ja, es gibt hunderte, wenn nicht sogar tausende solcher Wörter, z.B.

> Schüler, Computer, Mädchen, Reifen, Kabel, Flügel

Alle Substantive mit dieser Eigenschaft gehören zur Deklinationsklasse S6. Darin gibt es männliche und sächliche Substantive, aber keine weiblichen.

Meiner Recherche zufolge enden alle Wörter in dieser Klasse auf -el, -er oder -en. Sonderfälle sind die Diminutive, die auf -lein oder -chen enden. Andere Endungen sind mir nicht untergekommen, ich habe aber keine handfesten Belege dafür gefunden, dass es nicht vielleicht doch auch Substantive mit anderen Endungen in S6 gibt.

---

Beispiele für **männliche Substantive** in der Klasse S6:

> **Singular → Plural**
>   der Artikel → die Artikel
>   der Titel → die Titel
>   der Zweifel → die Zweifel
>   der Spiegel → die Spiegel
>   der Flügel → die Flügel
>
> der Spieler → die Spieler
>   der Besucher → die Besucher
>   der Arbeiter → die Arbeiter
>   der Wiener → die Wiener
>   der Täter → die Täter
>   der Leiter → die Leiter (Vorgesetzter, Anführer)
>
> der Rahmen → die Rahmen
>   der Rücken → die Rücken
>   der Kuchen → die Kuchen
>   der Brunnen → die Brunnen
>   der Orden → die Orden

Dazu gehören fast alle Berufsbezeichnungen, die auf -er enden:

> Maurer, Bäcker, Schuster, Müller, Lackierer, Programmierer, ...

Aber auch viele Bezeichner von Bewohnern bestimmter geographischer Gebiete:

> Engländer, Araber, Amerikaner, Saarländer, Londoner, Berliner, Hamburger, Römer, ...

---

**sächliche Substantive** in der Klasse S6:

> **Singular → Plural**
>   das Mittel → die Mittel
>   das Drittel → die Drittel
>   das Kapitel → die Kapitel
>   das Rätsel → die Rätsel
>
> das Opfer → die Opfer
>   das Theater → die Theater
>   das Wetter → die Wetter
>   das Fenster → die Fenster
>   das Feuer → die Feuer
>
> das Leben → die Leben
>   das Unternehmen → die Unternehmen
>   das Zeichen → die Zeichen
>   das Verfahren → die Verfahren
>   das Rennen → die Rennen
>
> das Mädchen → die Mädchen
>   das Säckchen → die Säckchen
>   das Kaninchen → die Kaninchen
>   das Kindlein → die Kindlein 
>   das Büchlein → die Büchlein

Dazu gehören alle Diminutive (Verkleinerungsformen) die auf -lein oder -chen enden

---

Aber:

> der Vogel → die Vögel
>   der Apfel → die Äpfel
>   das Hotel → die Hotels
>
> der Bruder → die Brüder
>   die Leiter → die Leitern (Aufstiegshilfe mit Sprossen)
>
> der Boden → die Böden

Diminutive, die auf -erl enden, gehören in den meisten Fällen auch nicht zu S6:

> das Schmankerl → die Schmankerln
>   das Kipferl → die Kipferln
>   das Sackerl → die Sackerln

(Die meisten dieser Wörter werden nur im österreichischen Hochdeutsch verwendet)

Comment: Interessanterweise würde ich als in Deutschland lebender Deutschsprachiger den Plural zu den österreichischen Diminutiven durchaus ohne das *n* bilden; die Pluralform wäre also wieder identisch mit der Singularform (vgl. z.B. ["Die Kipferl mit dem Backpapier vom Blech ziehen (...) die heißen Kipferl (...)"](https://www.oetker.de/rezepte/r/vanillekipferl.html); für "Schmankerl" zählt der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmankerl) auch beide Pluralformen auf).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -  In der Tat. Der richtige Plural von Kipferl ist Kipferl. (Jetzt ducke ich mich, denn ich erwarte eine zornig in meine Richtung geworfene Sachertorte.)

Comment: Wiktionary kennt kein *Kipferl* (anderswo als *Croissant* bekannt), wohl aber das Vanille*kipferl* und nennt dafür beide hier diskutierten Pluralformen: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vanillekipferl Ich weiß nicht, wie weit nach Norden das Gebiet geht, in dem das Wort *Kipferl* verwendet wird, aber ich vermute, dass es innerhalb dieses Verbreitungsgebiet regionale Unterschiede in der Pluralbildung gibt.

Answer (score 5):

Die größte Gruppe von Nomina mit [Nullplural](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Der_Nullplural) sind Maskulina und Neutra, die auf *-el, -en, -er* enden.

> der Nebel, Spiegel, Zweifel – das Kabel, Mittel, Viertel
>   der Brunnen, Knochen, Streifen – das Eisen, Wesen, Zeichen
>   der Bürger, Koffer, Treffer – das Fenster, Lager, Zimmer

Hinzu kommen die Neutra der Form *Ge- -e* wie *Gebäude* sowie Diminutiva mit *-chen* und *-lein*. Feminina ohne Pluralendung sind nur *Mutter, Tochter* (beide mit Umlaut).

Einzelgänger: *das Knie* (für die Sprecher, die im Plural [kni:] sagen); *der Käse*.

Comment: Gute Klassifikation.

Comment: Ich halte es für fragwürdig, "Mutter" und "Tochter" hier aufzuführen. Zwar merkst du richtig an, dass im Plural ein Umlaut hinzukommt. Einerseits war jedoch, selbst wenn dieser Umlaut in der Definition des Nullplurals enthalten sein sollte (der verlinkte Artikel lässt das Gegenteil vermuten), explizit nach Pluralformen gefragt, die überhaupt keine Änderungen im Vergleich zum Singular aufweisen. Andererseits könnten die Beispiele bei (hier durchaus möglichen) fremdsprachigen Besuchern den Irrglauben bestärken, Umlautpunkte seien "nur" Aussprachehinweise wie Akzentzeichen, die man einfach ...

Comment: ... ignorieren und stattdessen den zugrundeliegenden Vokal verwenden kann.

Comment: Ich bin kein Fan der Unterscheidung von Nullplural und Umlautplural. Ich sehe den endunglosen Plural analog zum e-Plural: die Maskulina und Neutra haben in beiden Fällen lexikalischen Umlaut (d.h. sie können Umlaut haben oder auch nicht, das muß man lernen). Ich sehe aber das Problem und habe die Formulierung angepaßt.

Answer (score 2):

There are many: usually they are nominalised verbs. Formula:

> remove the last **n** in the *verb in infinitve*, replace it by **r**

Example: *machen* -> *der Macher* (pl. *die Macher*).

Probably you will find some exceptions, but you'll also find many.

Comment: Ja, richtig. Ich habe von solchen vergessen. Gibt es aber auch manche, die sich nicht auf Menschen beziehen?

Comment: @sermonionx _"Gibt es aber auch manche, die sich nicht auf Menschen beziehen?"_ Ja, z.B. _Der Felsen => Die Felsen_

Comment: _@c.p_ _"There are many: usually they are nominalised verbs. Formula:"_ OP: _"Bitte antwortet auf Deutsch"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ wer unbedingt die Antwort auf Deutsch will, der soll die Sprache von vornherein festlegen. Verwirrend war hier, dass der OP englische Worte verwendet hat. Ich habe gar nicht die Sprache der Frage gemerkt.